# Removing items from an ngList in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ngList within an text box to get and post data to my server. The issue I've found is that while I can directly affect the generated array by removing indexes, when removing an item this way, the string in the input field is left unaffected.

The problem here is that as soon as the text field is modified, whatever is contained in that field immediately updates the model, restoring whatever items were removed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/EqkWwyLwvHrrhT6epOYP?p=preview

Does anyone have a solution for updating the string within the text field to match the model as the model is updated? My thought was to use an $apply either on my function or within a $watch but in both cases I got $apply in progress errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.states.splice(index, 1);
```

It will not update ng-list because the change mechanism only invoked if previous value is not equal current value **strictly**...

So if you will create new instance instead of the splice current one nothing will be invoked because it is the same array instance so replace this code with the current one and it will be  what you want...

```
var tmpList = angular.copy($scope.states);
tmpList.splice(index, 1);
$scope.states = tmpList;
```

and here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/oeY7yi5J2teC7CtkJ4Br?p=preview)

Comment: Interesting. Thank you very much. Works perfectly.